# SQL Server Management Studio quickly locate column?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm using SSMS and our tables have a lot of columns, so it gets frustrating trying to scroll and try to find a column. Is there a way to quickly locate a column?

Comment: Why do you need to "find" it - if you already know about it, what are you actually doing?

Comment: We have multiple tables with 30+ columns on a legacy database, so when I'm working in a table, I want to quickly check if it has a column without setting up a query.

Comment: Like using something like ctrl-f would be nice, and just type in the column name, and it would bring me to that column.

Comment: `select top 1 * from MyTable`? I don't really understand how you hope to speed things up from having to look through the column list?

Comment: Use SSMS Object Explorer, F7; you can start typing and "quickly" jump to the column in the list alphabetically.... if that's what you mean by "quickly locate".

Answer (score 1):

You can select from the sys tables

```
select c.name 
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id
where t.name = 'YOURTABLENAME'
and c.name like '%column looking for%'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find database objects (e.g. tables, columns, triggers) by name - have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??